# Gensim: quality of word2vec model seems not to correlate with num of iterations in training

Tags: python, word2vec

I'm playing with gensim's wordvec and try to build a model using the terms from a large medical thesaurus as sentences. There are about 1 million terms (most of the multiword terms which I treat as sentences) and the hope is, that if `word2vec` sees terms like "breast cancer" and "breast tumor" etc. it will be able to conclude that "cancer" and "tumor" are somewhat similar.

I run experiments in which I track how similar terms like that are when using different numbers of iterations but it seems that the results don't correlate. I'd expect that when considering word pairs like (wound, lesion), (thorax, lung), (cancer, tumor) etc, when going from 5 to 100 iterations there'd be a tendency (even if small) that the one word in the pair is "more similar" to the the other as the number of iterations grows. But no, results appear pretty random or even getting worse.

Specifically: I loop with 1,5,10,20,50,100 iterations and train a w2v model and then for my word pairs above check the rank of the 2nd word in the list (say "lung") of similar words (as returned by w2v) for the first word (say "thorax"), then sum up and build the average. And the average rank is growing (!) not decreasing, meaning as training proceeds, the vectors for "lung" and "thorax" move further and further away from each other.

I didn't expect gensim to detect the clean synonyms and also perhaps 'only' 1 million terms (sentences) is not enough, but still I am puzzled by this effect.

Does anyone have a suspicion?

====================================================

Added after comments and feedback came in:

Thanks for the detailed feedback, gojomo. I had checked many of these issues before:

- yes, the thesaurus terms ("sentences") come in the right format, e.g. ['breast', 'cancer']
- yes, of the ~1mio terms more than 850.000 are multiword. Clear that 1-word terms won't provide any context. But there should be ample evidence from the multiword terms
- the examples I gave ('clinic', 'cancer', 'lung', ...) occur in many hundreds of terms, often many thousands. This is what I find odd: That not even for words this frequent really good similar words are suggested.
- you ask for the code: Here it is https://www.dropbox.com/s/fo3fazl6frj99ut/w2vexperiment.py?dl=0 It expects to be called (python3) with the name of the model and then the SKOS-XML files of a large thesaurus like Snomed

  python w2vexperiment.py snomed-w2v.model SKOS/*.skos
- I the code you see that I create a new model with each new experiment (with a different number of iterations) So there should be no effect that one run pollutes the other (wrong learning rate etc...)
- I have set min_count to 10

Still: the models don't get better but often worse as number of iterations grows. And even the better ones (5 or 10 iterations) give me strange results for my test words...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there's something wrong with your corpus prep, or training – usually word2vec can rank such similarities well.

Are you supplying the *terms alone* (eg `['breast, 'tumor']` or `['prophylaxis']` as very tiny sentences), or the *terms plus definitions/synonyms* as somewhat longer sentences?

The latter would be better.

If the former, then 1-word 'sentences' achieve nothing: there's no neighboring 'context' for word2vec to learn anything, and they're essentially skipped.

And mere 2-word sentences might get some effect, but don't necessarily provide the kind of diverse contexts helpful for training to induce the useful vector arrangements.

Also if it's 1-million 'sentences' of just 1-4 words each, it's kind of a small dataset, and individual words might not be appearing often enough, in sufficiently slightly-varied contexts, for them to get good vectors. You should check the words/tokens of interest, in the `model.wv.vocab` dict, for a `count` value that indicates there were enough examples to induce a good vector - ideally 10+ occurrences each (and more is better).

So: more data, and more diverse usages from the relevant domain, are always a good idea. A thesaurus *with synonyms* in each 'sentence', that are many words (5 to dozens), might be enough.

You don't show your code or training-parameters, but people tweaking the defaults, or following outdated online examples, can often sabotage the algorithm's effectiveness.

For example, it's distressingly common to see people who call `train()` multiple times, in their own iteration loop, to mismanage the learning-rate `alpha` such that some iterations run with a *negative* alpha – meaning every backpropagation serves to drive the context-vectors towards *lower* target-word predictiveness, the exact opposite of what should be happening. (It's best to either supply the corpus & `iter` on `Word2Vec` initialization, *or* call `train()` just once. Only advanced tinkerers should need to call `train()` multiple times.)

Similarly, while naive intuition is often "keeping more words/info must be better", and thus people lower `min_count` to 1 or 0, such low-frequency words *can't* get good vectors with just 1 (or a few) occurences, but since they are very numerous (in total), they *can* interfere with other words' meaningful training. (The surviving, more-frequent words get better vectors when low-frequency words are discarded.)

Good luck!